# Determine if an int value exists once in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I know you can use Any, Exists, and Single with LINQ but can't quite get this to work.  I need to do a lookup based on an id to see if it's in the array and make sure that there is only ONE match on that value.  because if there are 2 it's gonna cause an issue..the requirement that I'm checking is that the array only has one and only one of each ID in the array.

Here's what I tried

```
if(someIntArray.Single(item => item = 3)
    //... we found the value 8 in the array only once so now we can be confident and do something
```

Comment: And how is `Single()` not working for you?

Comment: answered my own question.  see the answer.

Comment: @svick How would it be working? :-/ It will throw a nice fat Exception if it finds 0 or 2+.

Comment: @pst “make sure that there is only ONE match on that value” Throwing exception otherwise could fit that description, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a One() extension method set for just this situation:

```
public static bool One<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
   var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
   return enumerator.MoveNext() && !enumerator.MoveNext();
}

public static bool One<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
   return sequence.Where(predicate).One();
}

//usage
if (someIntArray.One(item => item == 3)) ...
```

The problem with Single() is that it throws an exception if there isn't exactly one element. You can wrap it in a try-catch, but these are cleaner, and more efficient than Count() in most cases where there's more than one matching element. Unfortunately, there's no way around having to check the entire array to verify that there are either no elements or only one that matches a predicate, but this will at least "fail fast" if there are two or more, where Count() will always evaluate the entire Enumerable whether there's one matching element or fifty.

Comment: awesome extension method.  Can you explain your code above? I'm curious to learn what you did as I am not that versed in Generics or predicates yet..

Comment: The main work is done in the first method, which uses .NET's IEnumerable and IEnumerator implementations, which are found on virtually every collection type. The basic idea of an Enumerable is that you start at the beginning and advance one element at a time through the collection until you reach the end. Here, we care only that the Enumerable has only one element; that means that we should be able to advance to the first element of the Enumerable (with the first call to MoveNext()), but should not be able to advance to the second.

Comment: The second method simply wraps the built-in Where() Linq method with a call to the parameterless One() overload; what happens is that the Where() method goes through the Enumerable in element order, and when it finds an element that, if plugged into the predicate method as "item", returns the Boolean "true", it adds that element to its own set of Enumerable results. It's a little more complex, because the function evaluates "lazily" (at any given time it has only done enough work to produce the results needed so far), but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would solve this:

```
if (someIntArray.Count(item => item == 3) == 1)
{
    //only one '3' found in the array
    ...
}
```

Comment: What happens when you have an array of, say, 5000 ints that are all 3? This solution would go through every last index, when the answer to the question being asked is obvious after examining two indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this.

```
var targetNumber = 3;
var hasExactlyOne = someIntArray.Count(i => i == targetNumber) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ expression:

```
var duplicates = from i in new int[] { 2,3,4,4,5,5 }
                 group i by i into g
                 where g.Count() > 1
                 select g.Key
```

Results:

```
{4,5}
```

And of course you could check `duplicates.Count() > 0` or log the ones that are a problem or whatever you need to do.

Answer (score -2):

got it working:

```
if(someIntArray.Single(item => item = 3) > 0)
```

doh

Comment: I think you need to read what [`Enumerable.Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx) is supposed to do again.  That's not going to work as you expect it (ignoring the assignment there).

Comment: you're right, I thought it was working and is not.  You don't want an exception thrown, that's the issue.  I ended up using "Contains" instead..works fine for me...although in the end, for my needs I didn't need to make sure ONLY one existed afterall as I was able to check that further upstream...so yea I have yet to find an elegant code sugar for this one either.